# How to Use SQL SELECT WHERE LIKE with a string that has spaces?

Tags: php, sql

When I do, let's say for example, a search of 'hello' I get all instances where 'hello' is used. But if I search 'hello my' I only get instances where those two words follow each other.

```
$search = 'hello my';
$search = explode(' ', $search);
```

Once I've exploded it I'm not sure what to do, I've tried using a for loop like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($search); $i++) {
    $search = $search[$i];
}
```

And I've also tried putting my SQL SELECT inside the for loop so it does multiple searches but that hasn't worked. My SQL syntax looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%$search%';`

Comment: if the search term is `hello my` what do you want to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this to search for any of the words in your search string:

```
$search = 'hello my';
$search = explode(' ', $search);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR string LIKE '%", $search) . "%'";
echo $query;
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%hello%' OR string LIKE '%my%'
```

If you want to search for *all* words in the search string, change the `OR` in the above code to `AND` i.e.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%" . implode("%' AND string LIKE '%", $search) . "%'";
echo $query;
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%hello%' AND string LIKE '%my%'
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/O7ejo)